# system call to map memory to a file descriptor (inverse mmap)?

Tags: c, unix, posix, mmap, system-calls

I want to be able to map memory to a file descriptor so I can use some existing functions that need a file descriptor.  Here's essentially what I'm looking for:

```
void do_operation1(int fd);

char data[DATA_MAX] = { /* embedded binary data */ };
int fd = addr_to_fd(data, DATA_MAX);

do_operation1(fd);
/* ... operate on fd ... */
```

What system call, or calls, can I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should Check out `shm_open()`.

Answer (score 7):

Some implementations have `fmemopen()`. (Then of course you have to call `fileno()`).

If yours doesn't, you can build it yourself with `fork()` and `pipe()`.

Comment: It turns out that `fileno()` fails on both Linux/FreeBSD (and I presume others) when the `FILE*` comes from `fmemopen ` or something equivalent. Without a way to get the file descriptor, I'm not sure we have a solution.

Comment: `fmemopen` may also be implemented using `funopen` on BSD. One implementation is available at https://redmine.openinfosecfoundation.org/attachments/105/0001-fmemopen-wrapper-added-fix-compilation-problems-on-m.patch

Comment: `fork()` is rather heavy-weight for this purpose. I’d suggest using a thread instead. Would be even better to use `select()` to multiplex between reading and writing from the pipe, but I guess that isn’t an option here.

Comment: That won't work since `fmemopen()` just creates a `FILE*` backed by given memory buffer. No file descriptor created.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just `open(argv[0], ...)`, scan through the file to find where your binary data starts, `lseek()` there and done. That file won't have the length of your binary data of course.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot map "some existing memory buffer" to a file descriptor.** As said in a comment above, the `fmemopen()` function associates a memory buffer with a "FILE *" stream pointer which can be manipulated with the libc-provided streams functions. No file descriptor is allocated: the "FILE *" stream is a high-level abstraction and is NOT compatible with a file descriptor which is a low-level handle.

**Instead, you may want to allocate a new shared memory buffer and map it to a file descriptor.** This is widely used and known as a "memory-mapped file" in the Linux jargon.

You can use a file descriptor obtained with `open()` that refers to a file or a file descriptor obtained with `shm_open()` that refers to a shared memory object. Any file descriptor handle will do the job. You can then invoke `mmap()` to map the file descriptor to a shared memory buffer.

> Note: `mmap()` will fail if the file descriptor refers to a non-regular file such as a pipe, a socket or a character device file (e.g., `/dev/ttys001`). Due to this, you cannot usually create a memory-mapped file for the STDIN, STDOUT or STDERR file descriptors.

You can manipulate the memory buffer in an array-like fashion and modifications to the memory-mapped file are committed to disk. The opposite is also true, with any modifications made to the file (e.g., with a `write()` syscall) committed to memory as well.

---

The following snippet opens a file of your choice and maps it into memory. It will print the first 256 characters and replace them with "*" in the original file. Compile it with `cc mmap_test.c -o mmap_test` on a POSIX-compliant system.

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    int pagesize, fd;
    unsigned char *data;

    if ( ac < 2 ) {
        printf("Usage: %s <filepath>\n", av[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    pagesize = getpagesize();

    if ( (fd = open(av[1], O_RDWR)) == -1 ) {
        perror("Error: cannot open file for reading");
        return 1;
    }

    if ( (data = mmap(NULL, pagesize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED ) {
        perror("Error: cannot create memory-mapped file");
        return 1;
    }

    write(1, data, 256);
    memset(data, '*', 256);

    return 0;
}
```