# C++ MMap a file to memory and then get a file descriptor to that memory

Tags: c++, file, mmap, file-descriptor, shared-memory

I saw this post: [system call to map memory to a file descriptor (inverse mmap)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822040/system-call-to-map-memory-to-a-file-descriptor-inverse-mmap)

I would like a library that I have that wants a file descriptor in its interface to be able to be given a file descriptor that will read from the region of memory where I've `mmap`ed the file.

I need something to the effect of:

1. `mmap` the contents of a large file (5gb) to memory
2. Get a file descriptor to that memory region
3. Call a library that takes that file descriptor and do something

The original file descriptor I used for `mmap` won't work of course, since that refers to the file on disk.

So far I was able to `mmap` the file to the memory, however I called `fmemopen`, but `fileno` is not set when that function is called. Any pointers?

The reason that I am doing this is I'm trying to reduce the amount of copying the library does as it processes the data in the file.

Comment: You cannot do what you're asking. The reason you give is extremely general. Everybody wants their program to be as fast as possible and as effective as possible. Telling us that is like telling us that the reason you're doing this is that you want to be happy. What, exactly, do you hope to achieve by doing this? Is the goal to dump a large region of memory to a file as quickly as possible?

Comment: In essence, the program read a large file, and process the file, I want this process to be as fast as possible, I tried to use ramfs which increased the speed by a bit, but now, I am trying to do what I asked because then it would skip the overhead of the filesystem access created by using ramfs.

Comment: I edited your question to make what you're trying to do much clearer. I hope the edit is helpful and useful.

Answer (score 2):

In one sense, what you're asking seems trivial. In another sense, it's impossible.

If this region of memory represents a file you've already `mmap`ed, then you already have a file descriptor for it since you needed that file descriptor for the call to `mmap`. If you mapped it in `MAP_SHARED` mode, modifications to the file through the file descriptor should show up in memory automatically and modifications to memory should also show up in the file automatically. That's the whole point of `mmap` in `MAP_SHARED` mode.

Though, looking at the man page, it's possible you may have to call `msync` on some systems in order for the stuff you did to memory to show up in the file.

If you have some region of memory that you acquired using `malloc` or some similar means, and then just want this region of memory to acquire a file descriptor, that isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am only reading the Mmaped region, I am not doing any writing.

Comment: @Bill - Do you need to write out any information? If not, why wasn't just `mmap`ing the file good enough in the first place?

Comment: @Bill - Is it that you need to call code you can't fix that directly makes `read` calls to get the information from the file?

Comment: I don't need to write out any information, just pure reading. The library I am using expects a file descriptor (such as returned by open() ) to the file, but when I call fmemopen() on the region mapped by mmap, a file descriptor is not set. (So I can't call fileno() on the result of fmemopen())

Comment: @Bill - Yes, then what you want to do is simply impossible. You need to modify the library.

Comment: @Omnifarious, do yo have a code snipet or  a reference to an example of what you proposed? That would be great!